# Disapear element when off screen

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to disapear an element when is of screen and then appear the new one.
The problem is, that the element disapear even if it's not off screen but on every scroll.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    scrollHide('#zabiegi');
});

function scrollHide(sectionId) {
    if ($(window).width() < 968) {
        $(sectionId).each(function () {
            if (($(sectionId).find('.two').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
                $(sectionId).find('.two').stop().fadeOut( "slow", function() {
                    $(sectionId).find('.one').fadeIn();
                    updateMargin(sectionId,'.one');
                });
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

i've also tryied different approach this time - nothing happens and if statement always give false.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    scrollHide('#zabiegi');
});

function scrollHide(sectionId) {
    if ($(window).width() < 968) {
        $(sectionId).each(function () {

            var off = $(sectionId).find('.two').offset();
            var t = off.top;
            var h = $(sectionId).find('.two').height();
            var docH = $(window).height();
            console.log(t > 0 && t + h < docH);

            if (t > 0 && t + h < docH) {
                $(sectionId).find('.two').stop().fadeOut( "slow", function() {
                    $(sectionId).find('.one').fadeIn();
                    updateMargin(sectionId,'.one');
                });
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've found a solution. The problem was in conditional statement if.
Here is the code:

```
function scrollHide(sectionId) {
    if ($(window).width() < 968) {
        $(sectionId).each(function () {
            if (($(sectionId).find('.two').offset().top + $(sectionId).find('.two').outerHeight() - $(window).scrollTop()) < 0  ) {
                $(sectionId).find('.two').stop().fadeOut( "slow", function() {
                    $(sectionId).find('.one').fadeIn();
                    updateMargin(sectionId,'.one');
                });
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

But still got problem... above script works only when i scroll down not up
... so i've added to the conditional statement:

```
if (($(sectionId).find('.two').offset().top + $(sectionId).find('.two').outerHeight() - $(window).scrollTop()) < 0 || ($(sectionId).find('.two').offset().top - $(sectionId).find('.two').outerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop()) < 0 ) {
```

And in console.log output is ok - it shows 0 when i above the element, but still not working...